# How to calculate RMS current from the rated current? Are they the same in a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, current-limiting, voltage-reference, rms, stepper-driver

I want to use the TMC2130 driver with the stepper motor I show below. This driver has these main features amongst others:

- Integrated power MOSFETs handle motor currents up to 1.2A RMS (QFN package) / 1.4A RMS (TQFP) or 2.5A short time peak current per
  coil.
- Range of Vref values:

  - default: 1V (±0.2);
  - MAX: 2.4V;
  - MIN: 0V;

### Stepper motor current

I have these motor specifications, I know the **rated current** that the motor can use

[image: stepper_motor]

I need to set the parameter X_CURRENT in the Marlin firmware that is the maximum that the stepper driver TMC2130 should give:

```
#if AXIS_IS_TMC(X)
    #define X_CURRENT        800           // (mA) RMS current. Multiply by 1.414 for peak current
    #define X_CURRENT_HOME   X_CURRENT     // (mA) RMS current for sensorless homing
    #define X_MICROSTEPS     16            // 0..256
    #define X_RSENSE         0.11
    #define X_CHAIN_POS      -1            // <=0 : Not chained. 1 : MCU MOSI connected. 2 : Next in chain, ...
#endif
```

The line comment says I need to multiply `RMS current x 1.41` and set the value. But I am not sure if the rated current I saw in the motor specificatios is the same as this RMS current.

I have also read [here](https://www.machinedesign.com/archive/article/21812234/stepper-phase-current-made-easy) that the current can be written in many forms in the motor specifications:

> Stepmotor-current ratings come in many forms such as amps/phase, amps RMS, average current, and even amps peak current.
>
> Labels on motors and motor data sheets typically list an amps/ phase rating. amps/phase specifies how much average current each winding or phase can handle without burning out the motor. It should be obvious that this value is the same as the amps RMS rating.
>
> To help with the calculation, assume the current for each phase is 1 A when both phases are powered, and 1.41 A when only one phase has power.

### How to calculate RMS?

If I take into account all of the information above I could get the value in different ways:

```
X_CURRENT = RMS current * 1.41 = 1.3 * 1.41 = 1833 mA

// or

RMS current = Max current / 1.41 = 1.3 / 1.41 = 0.92 A
X_CURRENT = RMS current * 1.41 = 0.92 * 1.41 = 1300 mA
```

Which is the right one?

### Get the X_CURRENT from the Vref

I have seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUadiW5QLBE) from **Teaching Tech** where the guy apply these formulas:

```
RMS current = Max current / sqrt(2)
Vref = (RMS current * 2.25) / 1.77
Using 90% Vref is safer
```

For some reason, the guy also says that in his case the `Vref` concide with the value that he should write in the `X_CURRENT` parameter

```
Vref = 0.76 V  =>  0.76 A = 760 mA
```

So taking into account this, I would get another different value:

```
RMS current = 1.3 A
Vref = (RMS current * 2.25) / 1.77 = 1.65 V
90% Vref = 1.49 V  =>  1.49 A = 1490 mA
```

Although I did not find the formulae for the Vref in the [TMC2130 Datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet_Rev1.11.pdf)

### Doubts

- Is the guy of Teaching Tech assuming that the resistance is 0 to convert the V to A directly?
- Are some of these parameters the same thing?: `Rated current =? RMS current`,  `Max current = Peak current`. How to calculate the RMS current if they are not the same?
- What I should write in the `X_CURRENT` parameter?
- What Vref should I use?

**Note**: I am going to plug the stepper driver to a Ramps 1.6+ board with 12V DC if that changes something.

Comment: "The line comment says I need to multiply RMS current x 1.41" (to get peak current.) This is only true for AC sine wave signals (and only very rarely by coincidence for other waveforms). If you're pulsing a DC supply, as you are for stepper motors, you'll need a different factor to convert between peak and RMS current. Add some more complexity if you have ramped edges to the pulses.

Comment: @GrahamNye thanks for commenting. And how I find that factor? I believe I will get the `RMS current = 1.3 A / 1.41 = 0.92 A` and I will set the 90% of the value directly in `X_CURRENT => 0.92 * 0.9 = 828 mA`